# How to target value option with css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to target my value option `page 1 of X`. It seems this is defined as a value option. Can i just target the div class to move it down the page slightly to align with another element?

Html:

```
<div class="pager">
<form class="awpcp-pagination-form" method="get">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="results">                                                                         
                        <option value="5">5</option>                                                                                                          
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>                                                                                                          
                        <option value="20">20</option>                                                                                                   
                        <option value="30">30</option>                                                                                    
                        <option value="40">40</option>                                                                                                                       
                        <option value="50">50</option>                                                                                                                                      
                        <option value="60">60</option>                                                                                                
                        <option value="70">70</option>                                                                                             
                        <option value="80">80</option>                                                                                     
                        <option value="90">90</option>                                                    
                        <option value="100">100</option>                                                               
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: Your question is unclear? Are you trying to position your <select> element? if so target the select not the option element.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite undefined, but assuming you want a way to target the element and based on the provide HTML this are ways to target the specific HTML elements.

```css
/* Pagination container */
.awpcp-pagination-form {
  outline: 1px solid purple;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Only the selection within container */
.awpcp-pagination-form select {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}


/* or */

select[name="results"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="pager">
  <form class="awpcp-pagination-form" method="get">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>
            <select name="results">
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="40">40</option>
              <option value="50">50</option>
              <option value="60">60</option>
              <option value="70">70</option>
              <option value="80">80</option>
              <option value="90">90</option>
              <option value="100">100</option>
              <option value="500">500</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you can do this using margins with css.

`.divclass{
     margin-top: 2%;
}`

Something like that might work.  You can also try using Flex-Box or Grid.

Good luck!